# ASP.NET MVC 3 Admin and Member setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC so wondering if anyone could provide tips on how best to setup the following structure so that it is a well-designed web application.

I am using the default ASP.NET MVC 3 Project Template in Visual Studio 2010.

The application will have the following roles: Admin, Tutor and Client.

I'm under the impression that for the site functionality I should be implementing separate Controllers and Views for each role.

How about if an Admin user can add information against a Tutor or Client. Would this functionality be added to an AdminController and an Admin specific View?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Depending on your site design you may want to use Areas to isloate all functionality of a specific role type to a subset of pages. For example, an area for "admin" would create a seperate living space in your project for all admin pages. It would also make all pages under /admin/{controller}/{action} by default.

Comment: @Splash-X, unless this will be a large application, I would advise against areas. Areas are good for preventing or resolving controller explosion in the root Controllers folder / namespace. Sounds like Sean may only want 3 controllers. Splitting this by area could add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: The application does have the potential to get bigger. As I am new to MVC, I'm not sure if I want to add another aspect to get my head round just yet - unless using Areas is the best way forward

Comment: @olivehour In my opinion, Areas provide an excellent way to split user functionality. If you consider the most basic administrative functions that could be performed on a "Tutor" or "Client", those actions would be littered all over the root controllers. You would have to place authorize filters on every action and manage those for the life of the application. While areas are not for every project, most of the time areas are a good fit when you need to split functionality.

Comment: @SeanDooley, areas can be hard to get your head around at first. Unless you have a good MVC3 book with a good explanation of areas, and how they work with namespaces / routing, forgo them for now. I agree they can be beneficial for large projects, but detrimental to smaller ones. And if you want to manage Authorize filters, it is easier if you write unit tests to back them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Authoirization (against your 3 roles), this is most easily handled at the action method level. You decorate the action method with [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")].

Regarding your controller and view design, it can depend on what you want your URL structure to look like, and whether you want to follow MVC3 conventions.

By convention, your URL schema will look like this:

```
www.site.com/controllerName -- defaults to index action method
www.site.com/controllerName/action -- specific action method
www.site.com/controllerName/action/id -- send optional argument to action method
www.site.com/controllerName/id -- send optional argument to index action method
```

So if you want your URL's to be /Admins/dosomething, /Tutors/dosomething, and /Clients/dosomething, and you want to adhere to the MVC conventions, name your controllers according to your role names.

If you want an admin to perform a tutor function, add this to the action method:

```
public class TutorsController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Tutor,Admin")]
    public ActionResult DoSomething(string id) 
    {
        var isAdmin = User.IsInRole("Admin");
        // ...do stuff
    }
}
```

With that said, there's nothing stopping you from breaking the conventions, and designing your URL schema separately from your controller & action method schema. It will just be more work because you will have to create custom routes.

**Answer to comments 1 & 2**

Your second comment is closer, and [Bassam Mahanni answered this correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838759/304832). The functionality for listing tutors should go on the tutors controller. If you plan to implement DI/IoC/Repository patterns, you will see why. Think of it in terms of which collection of entities the user is operating on. It is usually better to put all access to the Tutors entity set in the TutorsController. You can then limit Tutors from seeing this list with something like this:

```
public class TutorsController
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult ListAll()
    {
        // only admins can list all, tutors / clients cannot access this page
    }
}
```

If this is what you're after, there should be a corresponding unit test that makes sure this action method has the authorize filter, and that its Roles property equals "Admin".

The reason why I recommend this approach is because it will make it easier if you decide later to use constructor dependency injection for a repository. If you were to put some Tutors data access stuff in the AdminController, and other Tutors data access stuff in the TutorsController, you would have to inject your TutorsRepository into the constructor of both controllers.

Comment: All responses make perfect sense.

If I have got this right, say for example, an Admin Controller/View lists all Tutors with Edit, Details and Delete links.

Would the links on the Admin View redirect to the Tutor View or can the Admin Controller redirect to the Tutor Controller/View?

Comment: Or would the TutorController have a method that lists all Tutors which can only be accessed by Admin [Authorize(Roles = "Tutor,Admin")]? Therefore all methods are on the TutorController?

Comment: Those questions are for you to decide. How you organize your applications actions is totaly up to you. Some people will setup their controllers where the actions for the admin would live under the admin controller and have names like "DeleteTutor", "ViewTutor", etc. Some people might also place the actions in the Tutor controller and call them "Delete" and "View".  I myself would create an Area for Admin and create controllers in the Admin area that would manage Tutors or Clients. You can still have a Tutor or Client controller in the root or you could also create Areas for those if needed.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, they have been a great help! I will mark this as the answer, even though I know I will be asking many more questions throughout this project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you are modifying a tutor the TutorControllet should have this functionality regardless of the type of user that is performing the modification.